# To find the generalized expression

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to approach to the solution for finding a generalized expression for this definite integral: $$\int_a^{a \sqrt{2}} x^n \arccos\frac{a}{x} \mathrm{d}x$$

I approached this expression in finding the average point on a square just like the one for a circle will be at a distance of $\frac{2r}{3}$ from the center, similarly for a square i took a vertex as a reference and proceeded on diagonal line i.e. form $x=0$ to $x=a$

Kindly help in finding an generalized expression, particularly for $n$ as $1$ and $2$

Comment: https://files.fm/f/uvcfa8kj is the problem, i can not find any way to start, someone help!

Answer (score 3):

Apart from a factor $a^{n+1}$ this is about the quantities
$$K_n:=\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}t^n\arccos{1\over t}\>dt\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
Substituting ${\displaystyle t:={1\over\cos\alpha}}$ $\bigl(0\leq\alpha\leq{\pi\over4}\bigr)$ and integrating by parts we obtain
$$K_n=\int_0^{\pi/4}{\sin\alpha\over\cos^{n+2}\alpha}\,\alpha\>d\alpha={\alpha\over(n+1)\cos^{n+1}\alpha}\biggr|_0^{\pi/4}-{1\over n+1}\int_0^{\pi/4}{d\alpha\over\cos^{n+1}\alpha}\ ,$$
hence
$$K_n={1\over n+1}\bigl(2^{(n-3)/2}\pi -I_n\bigr)\ ,\quad{\rm whereby}\quad I_n:=\int_0^{\pi/4}{d\alpha\over\cos^{n+1}\alpha}\qquad(n\geq0)\ .\tag{1}$$
One computes
$$I_0=\log\bigl(1+\sqrt{2}\bigr),\quad I_1=1\ .\tag{2}$$
In order to obtain a recursion formula for the $I_n$ we consider
$$\eqalign{I_n-I_{n-2}&=\int_0^{\pi/4}{\sin\alpha\over \cos^{n+1}\alpha}\,\sin\alpha\>d\alpha={\sin\alpha\over n\cos^n\alpha}\biggr|_0^{\pi/4}-\int_0^{\pi/4}{d\alpha\over n\cos^{n-1}\alpha}\cr  &={2^{(n-1)/2}\over n}-{1\over n} I_{n-2}\ .\cr}$$
It follows that
$$I_n={1\over n}\bigl(2^{(n-1)/2}+(n-1)I_{n-2}\bigr)\qquad(n\geq2)\ ,$$
so that together with $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can recursively determine the $K_n$ for all $n\geq0$.

Comment: Very elegant solution, for sure !

Answer (score 2):

Making $x=\frac ta$, the problem reduces to $$K_n=a^{n+1}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 t^{-(n+2)} \cos ^{-1}(t) \, dt$$Using a CAS, we can get the antiderivative
$$I_n=\int t^{-(n+2)} \cos ^{-1}(t) \, dt$$

$$I_n=\frac{  \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{n}{2};1-\frac{n}{2};t^2\right)-n \cos
   ^{-1}(t)}{n (n+1)\,t ^{n+1}}$$ Using the bounds, almost as Mariusz Iwaniuk answered,
 is given by
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{a^{n+1}}K_n=2^{\frac{n-3}{2}} \left(\pi  n-2 \sqrt{2} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{n}{2};1-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+\sqrt{\pi }\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(1-\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\right)}$$  making
$$K_1=\frac{\pi -2}{4}  a^2$$
$$K_2=\frac{1}{6} \left(\sqrt{2} (\pi-1) -\sinh ^{-1}(1)\right) a^3$$
$$K_3=\frac{3 \pi -4}{12}  a^4$$
$$K_4=\frac{1}{40}  \left(\sqrt{2} (8  \pi -7)-3 \sinh ^{-1}(1)\right)a^5$$
$$K_5=\frac{15 \pi -14}{45}  a^6$$
$$K_6=\frac{1}{336}  \left( \sqrt{2} (96  \pi-67) -15 \sinh ^{-1}(1)\right)a^7$$
$$K_7=\frac{35 \pi -24}{70}  a^8$$
$$K_8=\frac 1{3456} \left( \sqrt{2}(1536  \pi-853) -105 \sinh ^{-1}(1)\right)a^9$$
$$K_9=\frac{4 (315 \pi -166)}{1575} a^{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

With [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) help,general integral is:

$\int_a^{a \sqrt{2}} x^n \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{x}\right) \, dx=\frac{2^{-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{n}{2}} a^{1+n} \pi }{1+n}+\frac{a^{1+n}
   \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(1-\frac{n}{2}\right)}{n (1+n) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\right)}-\frac{2^{n/2} a^{1+n} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{n}{2};1-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)}{n (1+n)}=\frac{2^{-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{n}{2}} a^{1+n} \pi }{(1+n)^2}+\frac{2^{-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{n}{2}} a^{1+n} n \pi }{(1+n)^2}+\frac{a^{1+n}
   B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 (1+n)^2}+\frac{a^{1+n} n B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2
   (1+n)^2}+\frac{a^{1+n} \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(-\frac{n}{2}\right)}{(1+n)^2 \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\right)}$

Where:$\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{n}{2};1-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is hypergeometric function,
$B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is  incomplete beta function.

Mathematica code:

```
(2^(-(3/2) + n/2) a^(1 + n) \[Pi])/(1 + n) + (a^(1 + n) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1 - n/2])/(n (1 + n) Gamma[1/2 - n/2]) - (
2^(n/2) a^(1 + n) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -(n/2), 1 - n/2, 1/2])/(n (1 + n))
```

Or:

```
(2^(-(3/2) + n/2) a^(1 + n) \[Pi])/(1 + n)^2 + (
2^(-(3/2) + n/2) a^(1 + n) n \[Pi])/(1 + n)^2 + (
a^(1 + n) Beta[1/2, -(n/2), 1/2])/(2 (1 + n)^2) + (
a^(1 + n) n Beta[1/2, -(n/2), 1/2])/(2 (1 + n)^2) + (
a^(1 + n) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[-(n/2)])/((1 + n)^2 Gamma[-(1/2) - n/2])
```

for $n=1$ integral is:

$$\frac{\pi  a^2}{4}-\frac{a^2}{2}$$

for $n=2$ integral is:

$$\frac{\pi  a^3}{3 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{a^3}{3 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{6} a^3 \ln \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)+\frac{1}{12} a^3 \ln (2)$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am very much thankful to all the three Samaritans namely Christian Blatter, Mariusz Iwaniuk & Claude Leibovici.

I am not writing an answer but to upload a photo i used this shortcut. Blame it on no knowledge of MathJx, Apologies!

I want to express why this problem came. A question i saw somewhere was to find the average point on a square like its a circle of radius 2r/3 centered at center of a disc in the latter's case.

Using the conventional method to find the solution, an expression came which on applying the results from above three people give the answer as ---

The average point is at a radial distance of 0.765*side from any vertex inside a square for which i am attaching a photo.

However as per the answer to the same question here [What is average distance from center of square to some point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15580/what-is-average-distance-from-center-of-square-to-some-point?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), its a circle of radius = 0.382*side centered at center of square and a graphical result, as i understand, is like in second image.

Kindly highlight the discrepancy in my approach if its faulty.[image]