# Expected range of distances from the center within a sample of random points in a square

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $n$ points are uniformly and randomly selected in  a square bounded by lines $ x=0,y=0,x=1,y=1.$ Let $X$ be the distance of a point from the centre $(1/2,1/2)$.Can we analytically calculate  the density function of the range of $X$.i did a MATLAB simulation

```
for k=1:1000  
       for i=1:1000  
                x1(i)=rand();    
                x2(i)=rand();  
                y1(i)=rand();  
                y2(i)=rand();  

                d(i)=sqrt((x1(i)-0.5)^2+(y1(i)-0.5)^2);  
                range=max(d)-min(d);  
       end  
       r(k)=range  
end  
avg=sum(r)/1000  
plot(r)
```

I got the average value of range as 0.67 .References  and books for similar problems involving random   distances  between points  are also requested
P.S:-Some experts are suggesting that my problem might be a duplicate of problem which talks about the average distance of a random point in   a square .While the two problems might be apparently similar but my problem is different in that its aim to find the density function of the range $R$  of the distance  of a random  point from the centre of the square ,possibly as a function of $r$ itself just as talk of the pdf $f(y)$ of a random variable $Y$.Further ,while it is relatively straight forward  to calculate the pdf of minimum and maximum of a rv ,it is an entirely different problem to compute the pdf of the range

Comment: somebody kindly tell me how I can highlight the code part in a nice way  and upload images

Comment: Hey, I was trying to make the code look nice! Why did you erase my changes? Also, it's not clear what you're asking, here. Do you think the answer is wrong, or what is your question?

Comment: @MattiP. did great job, let him to help you....

Comment: sorry @MattiP i just happened to add  a couple of lines at a wrong time.I am extremely sorry

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15580/what-is-average-distance-from-center-of-square-to-some-point

Comment: @MattiP. I think my question is clear .I am just asking whether there is some analytical way of finding  density function the range of distances from A(1/2,1/2) of n random points in the above square  as a function of  distance of a point from A and  the parameter n

Comment: That $0.67$ feels awfully high given that the distance to the corners (=the maximum) is $\sqrt{1/2}\approx0.707$. I got $\approx0.38$. Why is your code posting the average range of a sample of 1000 points? That's not what the title question is asking?

Comment: Oh, you really want the expected *range*. Then the question is underspecified. You need to fix the sample size (1000 in your code). If you let that $\to\infty$, then within each set you get closer and closer to the maximum.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I re ran the code ..giving me the same results.And i think it is not surprising because we are computing the range  .BTW, would you mind sharing your code or pointing whether there is something wrong with my code

Comment: That $0.38$ is the average of `d`. It was not clear to me initially that you had a double loop. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I did not understand that you are only interested in the distribution of the `range` variable. Anyway, my other point was that the result depends on the number of tests in the inner loop. Undoubtedly you know this, but without fixing the length of the inner loop we cannot have comparable numbers.

Comment: The main question really is that you describe a distribution, and are asking about the expected bevahior of the difference between maximum and minimum within a sample from that distribution. That was not clear.

Comment: Anyway, once you have the cumulative distribution, you can apply [the principles outlined here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/313390/11619) to get the cdf of the maximum. Similarly for the minimum.

Comment: so kind of @JyrkiLahtonen.Will try to figure out

Comment: This paper is great and has some details towards goals such as yours:
https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/boxintegrals.pdf